# Filtering orders by status containing space

Tags: collection, order-status

I am building a php script for a magento site. The script is located in a subfolder to the document root and is called from cron/terminal. In this script I am trying to create a collection of orders filtered by order status. This is the code I'm using atm:

```
$orderStatuses = explode(",", $argv[4]);
$rightNow = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");
$midnightToday = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime('midnight'));

$salesToday = Mage::getModel('sales/order')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addFieldToFilter('status', array('in' => $orderStatuses))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('from' => $midnightToday,'to' => $rightNow))
    ->addAttributeToSelect('grand_total');
```

the following parameter is sent to `$argv[4]`: `'Processing,Payment Accepted,Complete'`

Orders with the status `Payment Accepted` are not included in the collection. I have tried to escape the white space in the parameter using `\` but the result remain the same. How can I modify my code to include statuses containing white space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you have to tweak your query a bit. You might want to see the performance hit on this.

First replace your input parameter's space with '%'.

```
$orderStatuses = preg_replace ( '/[^a-zA-Z\,]/i', '%', $argv[4]);
$orderStatuses = explode(',', $orderStatuses);
```

Then your `Payment Accepted` will be `Payment%Accepted`. Now tweak your query.

```
$salesToday = Mage::getModel('sales/order')
->getCollection()
->addAttributeToFilter('created_at', array('from' => $midnightToday,'to' => $rightNow))
->addAttributeToSelect('grand_total');

foreach ($orderStatus as $_status) {
  $salesToday->getSelect()->orWhere('status LIKE ?', "%$_status%");
}
```

I think this should work.

Comment: The `preg_replace('/[^a-zA-Z]/i','%',$argv[4])` command swapped both `white space` and `,` with `%` leaving this string: `Processing%Payment%Accepted%Complete`

Comment: oh! add \, as well .. My bad! I've edited the answer please see.

Comment: Thanks! That did it. The closing bracket on the foreach line is missing in case you want to fix that.

Comment: After further testing I have found out that you code does not work. It seems that the `$salesToday->getSelect()->orWhere('status LIKE ?', "%$_status%");` actually nullifies the first filter selecting all orders with a matching status regardless of date. I have also found out that my question a bit off. I thought I was filtering on the status label when I was actually filtering on the status_code which never contain spaces. Because of this I am thinking of deleting this question since it does not seem relevant. Would this be the right thing to do?